# Selecting input type based on drop down selection in Angular 2

Tags: html, angular

```
<select class="select-sm form-control staffPatient" [(ngModel)]="personType">
                             <option value="staff" selected="true">Staff</option>
                             <option value="patient">Patient</option>
                            </select>
```

Based on the selection I need to display the fields.

If it's staff, this will display

```
 <p-autoComplete [hidden]="personType != staff" [(ngModel)]="val" [suggestions]="staffInfoList" field="perscode" field="personName" [minLength]=4 
                                    (onSelect)="setPersonInvolved($event)"  
                                    (completeMethod)="getPersonalMast($event)" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></p-autoComplete>
```

If it's patient this will show

```
 <input [hidden]="personType != patient" type="text" required="" class="form-control search" (keyup.enter)="getPatientInfo($event)" >
```

Have written the code [hidden] but not working.
2. Tried selected="true" to make staff as default in dropdown but in that drop down default is coming empty

Comment: Try `this.personType = "staff"` to initialise.

Comment: Try this: `[hidden]="personType != 'patient'"` . Try to use patient/staff as string.

Comment: [hidden]="personType != 'patient'" - not working

Answer (score -2):

```
<select class="select-sm form-control staffPatient" #personType (change)='onChange(personType.value)'>
                         <option value="staff" selected="true">Staff</option>
                         <option value="patient">Patient</option>
                        </select>
```

Then in your .ts file

```
staff = false;
patient = false;
onChange(value) {
   if (value === 'staff') {
        this.staff = true;
    }if (value === 'patient') {
        this.patient = true;
    }
}
```

And finally

```
<p-autoComplete *ngIf='staff' [(ngModel)]="val" 
[suggestions]="staffInfoList" field="perscode" field="personName" 
    [minLength]=4 
                                (onSelect)="setPersonInvolved($event)"  
                                (completeMethod)="getPersonalMast($event)" 
[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"></p-autoComplete>
```

And

```
<input *ngIf='patient' type="text" required="" class="form-
control search" (keyup.enter)="getPatientInfo($event)" >
```